# HTML/PHP Form Creation

Tags: html

I am trying to create a webpage that has the following HTML form features on it. I am able to create the basic code; however, when I visit the page in a browser, everything comes up very cramped and close together, I was just wondering if someone could help me space things out correctly? Below is my code and what the spacing should look like:

```
<html>

<form action = "comment_process.php" method = "post">
    Name: 
    <input type = "text" name = "name"/> <br>

    Do you like this page?
    <input type = "radio" name = "answer" value = "Yes"> Yes 
    <input type = "radio" name = "answer" value = "No"> No <br>

    Comment:
    <textarea rows="3" cols="50" name = "name"/> </textarea> <br>

    Rating 
    <select name = "rating"> <br>
        <option value = "0"> 1 </option>
        <option value = "0"> 2 </option>
        <option value = "0"> 3 </option>
        <option value = "0"> 4 </option>
        <option value = "0"> 5 </option> 
    <input type = "submit" value = "go"/>
</form>

</html>
```

[image: Project]

Comment: do you have any CSS?

Answer (score 0):

There is one solution by [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/). I think it will be very helpful for your project. You must try it.

**It's result.**

---

[image]

---

There is a [code snippet](http://codepen.io/snave/pen/ozYPjK).

**There is a full code.**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.2" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/css/bootstrap.css" />
  <script data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.2" src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/twbs/bootstrap/v4-dev/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">

    <form action="comment_process.php" method="post">

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="answer">Do you like this page?</label>
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="Yes" /> Yes</label>
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="answer" value="No" /> No</label>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="comment">Comment</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" id="comment"></textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="rating">Rating</label>
        <select id="rating" name="rating" class="form-control">
          <option value="0"> 1 </option>
          <option value="0"> 2 </option>
          <option value="0"> 3 </option>
          <option value="0"> 4 </option>
          <option value="0"> 5 </option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" value="go" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```